# Need to clean If Not Intersect Is Nothing code on order form with multiple lines

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA. Wondering how I can make my code more efficient.

I've created an order form with 50 order lines, i.e. you can order at most 50 items using this sheet. Each item has 3 possible customizations which will determine the product SKU. I've written the following code to "reset" the customization choices if you change the item choice for each line (only showing code for first 3 lines, but this repeats for all 50 lines). Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L1RoomType")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("L1Dis").Value = Range("L1DisDefault").Value
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L1RoomType")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("L1Pwr").Value = Range("L1PwrDefault").Value
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L1RoomType")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("L1TM").Value = Range("L1TMDefault").Value
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2RoomType")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("L2Dis").Value = Range("L2DisDefault").Value
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2RoomType")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("L2Pwr").Value = Range("L2PwrDefault").Value
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2RoomType")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("L2TM").Value = Range("L2TMDefault").Value
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L3RoomType")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("L3Dis").Value = Range("L3DisDefault").Value
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L3RoomType")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("L3Pwr").Value = Range("L3PwrDefault").Value
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L3RoomType")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("L3TM").Value = Range("L3TMDefault").Value
End If
    
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage in the patterns in your naming.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim IntersectRange As Range
    Dim RoomNum As Long
    
    On Error GoTo EH ' Ensure events get turned back on
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    For RoomNum = 1 To 3 ' or 50?
        Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L" & RoomNum & "RoomType"))
        If Not IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
            Me.Range("L" & RoomNum & "Dis").Value = Me.Range("L" & RoomNum & "DisDefault").Value
            Me.Range("L" & RoomNum & "Pwr").Value = Me.Range("L" & RoomNum & "PwrDefault").Value
            Me.Range("L" & RoomNum & "TM").Value = Me.Range("L" & RoomNum & "TMDefault").Value
        End If
    Next
EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Kco, gland to help.  Since you are new here, [please see this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)